# codeigniter error :Message: Undefined variable: results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am adding users in a table through `CodeIgniter` form. `Insertion` is going fine. but after deleting selected record i am getting **undefined variable results**.
I also defined

```
 $results = NULL;
```

in my controller code.
What is happening with my code?

**Controller code**

```
$results = NULL;
$this->load->model('User');
$form_data['results'] = $this->User->view_table();
$this->load->view('User/User_login', $form_data);
```

**View Code  in user_login.php**

```
<?php 
            if(sizeof($results)>0){
                foreach ($results as $row){
                    echo "<tr style='text-align:center';>";
                    echo "<td>".$id=$row->id."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->first_name."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->last_name."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href = ".base_url().'Users/user_edit'.">Edit</a>|<a href=".base_url().'Users/user_delete/'.$id=$row->id.">Delete</a></td>";
                   // echo $id; die();
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            }else{
                echo "no record found";
            }

            ?>
```

**Error**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: results

Filename: User/User_login.php

Line Number: 44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isset` which checks that variable is defined or not

```
<?php 
        if(isset($results)){
            foreach ($results as $row){
                echo "<tr style='text-align:center';>";
                echo "<td>".$id=$row->id."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->first_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->last_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href = ".base_url().'Users/user_edit'.">Edit</a>|<a href=".base_url().'Users/user_delete/'.$id=$row->id.">Delete</a></td>";
               // echo $id; die();
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        }else{
            echo "no record found";
        }

        ?>
```

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

The `$results`  you have set this to null but you haven't pass this to view you have passed
`$form_data` to view generally `codeigniter` converts all the `keys` passed to view to variable therefore you see undefined message because your `$this->User->view_table();` returns nothing and it is assigned to `$form_data['results']`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `$this->User->view_table()` function sometimes return `NULL`. Check it.